# anaconda not opening it's just loading

Tags: anaconda, window

i am trying to open anaconda but it's only showing logo for some time then it closes. I Also update conda ,anaconda-navigator ,navigator-updater and i also reset it through anaconda prompt but it's not working for me.
when i type anaconda-navigator in command prompt then it showing error with status code 522 as you shown it below .

C:\Users\user>anaconda-navigator
2022-02-24 11:50:41,848 - ERROR ads._log_errors:23
Tried to load advertisement image from https://optimise2.assets-servd.host/voracious-blesbok/production/api/navigator/Navigator-Commercialv6.png?w=315&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=crop&dm=1643727003&s=77c3c1e618c897e6f1b9081f29103c53. Data is not fetched with status 522

Answer (score 0):

I have also exactly the same problem. I removed anaconda (python 3.7) and reinstalled the Anaconda 3.9. It was good yesterday and worked with. Suddenly it stopped working and I figured out that I can only launch it by "run as administrator". I wanted to launch it from the anaconda prompt but I got the same error as you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by change charset from utf-8 to gbk in file launch.py

Answer (score -1):

I accidentally found a workaround. I use a vpn client (pia vpn). Normally this is disabled when I'm programming. But I found that if I have activated vpn and call anaconda-navigator, it starts in a reasonable time. The error still appears but it looks like a timeout somewhere has been greatly shortened.